# Bounds dimension, scheme and projective dimension

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, krull-dimension

Is the dimension of a (commutative unital associative) algebra always bounded above by its protective (injective) dimension?

If not is it always bounded above by its global dimension?

Comment: I don't understand what *protective* dimension means. If this is the projective dimension, then which projective dimension has a ring? As a module over itself? Then it is $0$. The injective dimension of the ring over itself can be infinite, while the dimension is finite (e.g., for non-Gorenstein rings). If the ring is noetherian and local with $\operatorname{id}_RR<\infty$, then $\dim R=\operatorname{id}_RR$. (But maybe you want to investigate the non-noetherian case.) If the ring is noetherian and its global dimension is finite, then it is regular, so $\dim R=\operatorname{gldim}R$.

Comment: Maybe you want to make your question more specific. The title is also confusing (at least for me).